# How to do a Zoom in/out with Cardboard SDK for Android with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, zooming, google-cardboard, fieldofview

I'm building a Cardboard app with Unity3D that should be able to Zoom in/out with the Magnetic Trigger. 
In the StereoController.cs changed the MatchMonoFOV=1 and MatchByZoom=1.
Then i created a script with this method just for Zooming In:

```
public void TriggerStart()
{
    //This counts the number of active cameras and set the FOV to 40
        for (int i = 0; i < Camera.allCamerasCount; i++)
        {
                Camera.allCameras[i].fieldOfView = 40;
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, this works only in UnityEditor but not with the Headset.
Every kind of advice will be really appreciated!